# Using Jsoup to select classes and id

Tags: java, css, jsoup

I am using this as an example

http://www.shopping.com/digital-camera/products?CLT=SCH&KW=digital+camera

In the linke above there is a class

```
<span class="numTotalResults">
  Results 1 - 40 of 1500&#43;
</span>
```

I got it using

```
Document query_result = Jsoup.connect("http://www.shopping.com")
                .data("CLT", "digital camera")
                .post();
```

but when I

```
System.out.println(query_result.select(".numTotalResults"));
System.out.println(query_result.select("#quickLookItem-1"));
System.out.println(query_result.select("[name=D0]"));
```

Nothing happens,

while

```
System.out.println(query_result);
System.out.println(query_result.select("span"));
```

clearly prints out the values

The selector seems to work only with div and span and anchor, but I can' select the classes or the id

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Edit:

It seems like the post did not go through. I don't quite understand why it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using POST request, try GET one:

```
Document query_result = Jsoup.connect("http://www.shopping.com/digital-camera/products?CLT=SCH&KW=digital+camera")
            .get();
```

Take a look how does this search works. It doesn't use POST method and it keeps all search parameters in a query string. After this small change your first select example will work well.

Comment: Thanks it works, although I am a bit confused, when you query something don't you always post instead of get?

Comment: With forms like this (search form, filter form etc.) in most cases you use GET method. And the reason is very pragmatic - you can simply pass all query parameters in a URL using for e.g. pagination. If you would use POST in this case, you will have to store all query parameters somewhere (e.g. session) and manage the lifecycle of those one. That's why it's convenient to pass them through GET request. POST is mostly reserved for forms where you dont want to share anywhere the data that was posted, like user settings form, sign in/up form etc.